# Reading Integers From A Buffer into an Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, buffer

So I'm trying to store int values that have been read from the keyboard into an array of integers in C. Sample user input:

```
8 99 5 7 8
```

variable declarations:

```
int k;
int size;
char buf[100];
```

The above is my buffer and other variables for the array.
The below is to read the ints into the buffer.

```
printf("Please enter in the numbers for the array:\n");
fgets(buf, 100, stdin);
buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = '\0';

size = (strlen(buf)/2)+1;

int *array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
```

So that correctly allocates my array.

```
int i, j;
for(i = 0, j = 0; i < size; i++, j = j+2)
{
    array[i] = buf[j] - '0';
}
```

The above code actually works, but not for numbers that have double digits, only for numbers below 10 and above 0. How can I fix my code so that I correctly read in the integers? 
I have tried to do a `for` loop with `sscanf`, but that just leads to an array with only the first integer entered in all elements.

Comment: You might want to have a look at `strtol()`.

Comment: @EOF You mean `strtok()`?

Comment: Note: They say [you shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: @MikeCAT: No, I meant the "string to long" function called `strtol()`.

Comment: `strtok()` may be useful anyway.

Comment: @MikeCAT, I will fix the issue with the cast (like last time). However, I seem to understand the idea of strtok(), but once I get the token string (which would be the number string), how would I turn that token string into a number, with strtol()?

Comment: Actually, I think I undersatnd

Comment: "So I'm trying to store int values that have been read from the keyboard" - You don't enter int(eger) values, but characters. And you want to convert a character sequence of digits to an integer value. As @EOF wrote: `strtol` & family. Oh, and only cast **iff** 1) It is absolutely necessary **and** 2) You fully understand _all_ implications **and** 3) _fully_ accept them (this is a general rule - no exceptions!).

Answer (score 1):

> How can I fix my code so that I correctly read in the integers?

Use `strtol()` to parse the string as suggested by [@EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36025219/reading-integers-from-a-buffer-into-an-array-in-c/36025758#comment59701229_36025219).  It provides an end pointer where it left off.

```
long *array = malloc(sizeof *array * size);
if (array == NULL) Handle_OutOfMemory();

char *p = buf;
size_t i;
for(i = 0; i<size; i++) {
  // Cope with white space with nothing after it.
  while (isspace((unsigned char) *p)) p++;
  if (*p == '\0') break;

  char *end;
  errno = 0;
  long num = strtol(p, &end, 10);
  // If no conversion or out of range ...
  if (p == end || errno) {
    fprintf(stderr, "trouble converting `%s` into an integer.\n", p);
    break;
  }
  array[i] = num;
  p = end;
}

// Use array[0] ... array[i-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sscanf` or `strtol` to extract the numbers from the input string. In either case, you will be given three pieces of information from each call:

- an indication that a valid number was found
- the value of that number
- the location in the input array where the next number will be found

With `sscanf`, the return value indicates success or failure. For the `sscanf` in the sample code (see below), the return value is 1 for success, anything else is a failure. If successful, the value of the number is placed at the address specified, e.g. `&temp` in the sample code.

And here's the tricky part: you need the location in the array to start the search for the next number. `sscanf` has a special conversion for that, the `%n` conversion. The output from `%n` is the number of characters that were consumed while performing the conversion(s).

In the sample code below, I use a pointer `ptr` that initially points to the beginning of the input string. On each pass through the loop, `%n` is used in the `sscanf` to update variable `n`, which indicates how many characters were consumed converting the current number. By adding `n` to `ptr` in the `for` loop, the pointer is advanced to the next number.

```
int *array = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
int n = 0;
int i = 0;
for ( char *ptr = buf; *ptr; ptr += n )
{
    int temp;
    if ( sscanf(ptr, "%d %n", &temp, &n) != 1 ) {
        // error: not a number
        break;
    }
    array[i++] = temp;
}
```

---

As mentioned by @chux in the comments, adding a space to the format string `"%d %n"` will consume trailing whitespace after each number and set the value of `n` accordingly. Thus, if the input line contains only numbers, the loop will end when the `for` statement detects that `*ptr` has reached the NUL terminator. But if the input contains a non-number, then the loop will `break` when the `sscanf` fails. This can be used for error checking.

Comment: `"%d %n"` with a space nicely consumes trailing white space like `'\n'`.  Helps distinguish if `ptr` finished as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned int len=0,tmp=0;
char j,isnumber=0;
for(char*i=buf;j=*i;i++)
{
    if(j>='0'&&j<='9')
    {
        tmp=tmp*10+j-'0';
        isnumber=1;
    }
    else
    {
        if(isnumber)
            array[len++]=tmp;
        tmp=0;
        isnumber=0;
    }
}
```

Also, you don't need

```
buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = '\0';

size = (strlen(buf)/2)+1;
```

Comment: How do you declare (and initialize if you need) `array`?

Comment: `unsigned int array[50];`

Comment: Spaces are not just for indenting. They also greatly enhance readbility in-between tokens. And - unless there are good reasons not to - one should use the standard library's functions.

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers are coming from `stdin`, it's more effort to read them in as a string and convert them yourself than it is to have the standard library do it for you. Here I've hardcoded a maximum number of 100 integers. After the loop, `i` will represent the number of valid integers in `array`.

```
int array[100] = {0};
int i = 0;

while (i < 100)
{
    int input;
    int scanresult = scanf("%d", &input);

    if (scanresult == 1)
    {
        // 1 item was successfully scanned
        array[i] = input;
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        // either EOF was reached or the input was not scannable as an integer
    }
}
```